# Logging on to DevOps from Protractor automated test

Tags: azure-devops, protractor

I have an automated test that is required to access pages from our DevOps system.

Everytime the test runs, Azure DevOps requires username and password entry - which is fine and coded BUT then 2-part authentication kicks in.

I have tried putting in a long wait time, running the test and entering the verification code manually and clicking the 'allow for 60 days' checkbox but the next time the test is run, the same 2-Part authentication is required.

I guess I could leave a long wait and enter the code manually each time the test runs but it does seem to spoil the whole automated concept.

Anyone experienced this and got a way forward?

Thanks

David

Comment: What are you trying to access on the actual pages that you can't get at with the REST api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, is it possible that your Microsoft account has set up two-step verification?

If you turn on two-step verification, you’ll get a security code to your email, phone, or authenticator app every time you sign in on a device that isn't trusted. When two-step verification is turned off, you will only have to verify your identity with security codes periodically.

You can turn two-step verification on or off by the following steps:

1.Go to the [Security basics](https://account.microsoft.com/security/) page and sign in with your Microsoft account.

2.Select More security options.

3.Under Two-step verification, choose Set up two-step verification to turn it on, or choose Turn off two-step verification to turn it off.

4.Follow the instructions.

For details, please refer to this [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12408/microsoft-account-how-to-use-two-step-verification).